# How to remove null return value in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query :

```
SELECT * FROM 
        (select x.place_id as id_1, x.name as name_1 
        from n_hanhchinhxa p join hanhchinhxa_x x on p.osm_id = x.osm_id) as dad
        LEFT JOIN 
        (select x.parent_place_id as parent_1, x.place_id as id_2, x.name as name_2 
        from n_hanhchinhxa p join hanhchinhxa_x x on p.osm_id = x.osm_id)  as tmpPlaceId 
        on tmpPlaceId.parent_1 = dad.id_1
        LEFT JOIN 
        (select p.osm_id as osm_id_3, x.place_id as id_3, p.name as name_3, x.parent_place_id,x.geometry 
         from n_hanhchinhxa p join hanhchinhxa_x x on p.osm_id = x.osm_id) as tmp 
         on tmp.parent_place_id = tmpPlaceId.id_2;
```

and my query returns the information table as shown below : [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvwOW.png)

Is there a way for me to remove all returned rows with null columns (non-duplicate values ​​in the returned results are osm_id_3 and id_3) ?

I tried using DISTINCT but it didn't work. Thanks if someone help me !

Comment: use the predicate `WHERE my_column IS NOT NULL`

Comment: You are doing a `left join`  (which is a shortened version for `left outer join`)  to get those columns.  But that specifically says *f  no rows match the join condition then return null*. So are you specifically asking for nulls; then asking to eliminate them. Perhaps you can just change to inner join.

Comment: @Z4-tier all my input columns are valid.

Comment: @Belayer is there any other way than using ```left join``` ?

Comment: Try **inner join**. I have not tested that however as I have no sample data not actual table definition.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for myself:

```
SELECT * FROM (
        (select x.place_id as id_1, x.name as name_1 
        from n_hanhchinhxa p join hanhchinhxa_x x on p.osm_id = x.osm_id where x.admin_level = 4) as dad
        left JOIN 
        (select x.parent_place_id as parent_1, x.place_id as id_2, x.name as name_2 
        from n_hanhchinhxa p join hanhchinhxa_x x on p.osm_id = x.osm_id where x.admin_level = 6)  as tmpPlaceId 
        on tmpPlaceId.parent_1 = dad.id_1
        left JOIN 
        (select p.osm_id as osm_id_3, x.place_id as id_3, p.name as name_3, x.parent_place_id,x.geometry 
         from n_hanhchinhxa p join hanhchinhxa_x x on p.osm_id = x.osm_id where x.admin_level = 8) as tmp 
         on tmp.parent_place_id = tmpPlaceId.id_2
```

Just add 1 conditional sentence ._.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).